# What does "set" mean in "The NFL could be set to ban helmets"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "set" mean in the following:

> The NFL could be set to ban helmets.

I don't even know if it is verb or noun.

PS I not a native English speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: It essentially means "prepared" or "ready".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Set* there means "in position to", i.e. "ready to" or "prepared to".

When we are "set" or "all set", we're ready.

**She was all set to go out the door, when the phone rang.**

Answer (score 3):

On one hand, this is a typical "use your dictionary"-question, but then again, *set* has over a 100 definitions on [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/set). The one you want is this one (from [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/set_3)):

> 5. likely to do something; ready for something or to do something
>      set for something *The team looks set for victory.*
>      set to do something *Interest rates look set to rise again.*

Comment: It's certainly not suitable for ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd love to suggest moving it to ELL...

Comment: While it is not suitable for ELU, the fact that the dictionary entry for set is as long as it is really moves it from "use your dictionary" to "a reasonable question" IMO.

Comment: [Collins Reverso Dictionary's](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/to%20be%20set%20to%20do%20something) single entry for  "to be set to do something": exp.  
to be likely to do something  
_banks set to miss lending targets_ probably makes it genref too.

Comment: @Edwin: I think that's true so far as ELU is concerned, since we should expect the target user base here to know how to look up a *specific* idiomatic usage like this if they happen not to know it. But I agree with oerkelens that it would be fine on ELL, since I expect *most* "translating" dictionaries in the querent's native language probably wouldn't go into that much detail (and ***set*** *is* the ***definitive*** long and potentially confusing entry in English dictionaries! :)

Comment: It's certainly suitable for ELL.